# Positivity once $f'(x)$ and $-f(x)$ has the same sign

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Consider a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

- $f(0)>0$
- $f'(x)$ continuous in $(0, \infty)$ and $-f(x)$ has the same
  sign.

I must prove that $f$ is non-negative.

Suppose that there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t. {$ t; f(t)=-\epsilon$} is non-empty e let $T$ the infimum of this set. Once the function is continuous, $T$ is the first time in which $ f(T)\leq-\epsilon$. Also, there is an interval $(T-\tau, T+\tau)$ s.t. $f<0$ and so $f'>0$, then $f$ is increasing in this interval. This implies $f(T-\tau)<-\epsilon$. This is a contradiction once $T$ is the first time in which $ f(T)\leq-\epsilon$.

Is this argument valid?

Comment: $f(T-\tau)<-\epsilon$... So $T$ is not the first time that $f(T)\leq-\epsilon.$

Comment: @BobDobbs Yes, this is the contradiction. I'll complete with your statement, thank you. What do you think now?

Comment: I think you need to consider the set $\{t: f(t) \leq -\epsilon\}$ otherwise $T$ need not be the first time that $f$ is $\leq -\epsilon$.

Comment: Your argument is valid according to me. Another explanation can be  based on 
$${d\over dx}(f(x))^2=2f(x)f'(x)\le 0$$ Hence $f(x)^2$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: Shouldn't we also recall intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis, but if $t<T$ is s.t. $f(t)\leq-\epsilon$, then once $f(0)>0$, by continuity there is $t'<t<T$ s.t. $f(t')=-\epsilon$ (and $T$ wouldn't be the infimum), isn't?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc wow, great ideia. Thank you.

Comment: @BobDobbs yes, as said to Giorgos

Comment: That's correct but if you choose to go this way you have to mention this in your proof.

Comment: If $f(a)=0$ for some $a>0$ then $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge a,$ as $f^2$ is nonincreasing. In particular $f$ cannot admit negative values.